# How know if current item was deleted?

Tags: 2010, designer-workflow, move

I created a policy on a library which it's run after a month of document creation date and run a SharePoint 2010 workflow `Workflow A` which it gives the document creator a period `5 minutes` to fill document properties.

When the `document creator` fill the document properties then there is another workflow `Workflow B` on the library which it moves the document to another library.

I need a way to know if the document was moved by `Workflow B` after `Workflow A` running.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Add a hidden field in the destination list. Name it `MovedBy` and set default value to `empty`. Make this field hidden so normal user will not see this.

On `Workflow A`, when you move the document set the field `MovedBy` to `WorkflowA`.

Now to identify the documents you just need to look into the field `MovedBy`